# Regex - bracket identification

Tags: regex

Why can a regex correctly identify bracketing such as `((a))` but not `(((a)`? I don't have any specific regex in mind but I am curious on why it is the case.

Comment: I don't see the answer in this other question.

Comment: A regex can identify `(((a)`.  Just use `\(\(\(a\)`.  Please clarify what you are looking for.